# How to get info about specific user using github graphQL?

Tags: github, graphql

How can I get info about specific user or specific repo using github GraphQL? I've try this query:

```
{
  search (query: "torvalds", type: USER, first: 1){
    edges {
      node {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

but autocomplete for node show only __typename which return string "User".

[DEMO](https://graphql-explorer.githubapp.com/?variables=%7B%7D&query=%7B%0A%20%20search%20(query%3A%20%22torvalds%22%2C%20type%3A%20USER%2C%20first%3A%201)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20__typename%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to get information about a specific user is to use the `repositoryOwner` query, like so:

```
{
  repositoryOwner(login: "stubailo") {
    login
    ... on User {
      bio
    }
  }
}
```

Search is good too, but if you know the name of a user or organization, it's more direct to use the query above.

Comment: Any idea how we can search for a user who uses specific language?

Answer (score 8):

`search` returns a `SearchResultItem`, which is an interface. In order to access fields on it, you need to use a fragment on a concrete type like so:

```
{
  search (query: "torvalds", type: USER, first: 1){
    edges {
      node {
        ... on User {
          login
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I made a short video tour of GitHub's GraphQL API which you might find useful: https://youtu.be/6xO87LlijoQ

EDIT: If you're just looking for a user or org and know the exact name, @stubailo's answer is actually better. You'll still need to use a fragment for most fields, but you'll get just one result of type `RepositoryOwner`.

Comment: Any idea how we can search for a user who uses specific language?